# roslaunch irb_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i am trying to run this command it is saying resource is not found

but when i am trying to execute it for other models

roslaunch irb_6640_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch

i am having no problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203478/roslaunch-irb_moveit_config-moveit_planning_execution.launch/) by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-20**:
Please update your post with the **complete** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where did you get `irb_moveit_config` from?

The file `moveit_planning_execution.launch` is a non-standard file, added by ROS-Industrial to MoveIt packages for industrial robots.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishok](https://answers.ros.org/users/18841/nishok/) on 2015-02-20**:
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot

i have generated one through this tutorial

till step 2 every thing was fine i have some issues from step 3

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-20**:
Well, you'll have to add the `moveit_planning_execution.launch` file yourself. `resource not found` sounds like the launch file is referring to something that doesn't exist?